# SBT & Json4s serializing Joda Time: How can I access the .ext package?

Tags: scala, sbt, jodatime, json4s

In my Scala Spray.io application, I would like to turn some Joda `LocalTime` and `LocalDate` objects into JSON. This is apparently done by adding JodaTime support from Json4s to the `DefaultFormats` as follows:

```
object Json4sProtocol extends Json4sSupport {
  implicit def json4sFormats: Formats = org.json4s.DefaultFormats ++ org.json4s.ext.JodaTimeSerializers.all
}
```

But for some reason, I'm **unable to access** the `ext`package: `object ext is not a member of package org.json4s`. Any ideas why this can happen?

I'm well aware that it may be some problem in the way I load the dependencies. I added this line to my `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11",
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 7):

I found out the problem: I was not importing `json4-ext`.

I added that line in my `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.11",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext" % "3.2.11",
  ...
)
```

And it worked.